# Why everyone follows Joe Carroll on "The Following"?

Tags: the-following

I watch "The Following" for a while and I never got why people follow him. His followers do everything to ensure his wishes are granted and he is not very kind with them, although he wants to seem like a safe harbor. He is very selfish and doesn't seem to care to anyone, but he has a lot of people willingly to do everything only because he said so.

What is the reason behind the "cult" of Joe Carroll? What does he have that the "normal" society can't provide? I could say that is because our society rejects killers, but some of his followers only develop a "killer instinct" after being on his cult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've tagged this question about **The Following**, the truth is that this is a much, much broader question which is far more interested in the psychological reasoning behind people joining cults and their blind dedication and loyalty to their leaders.

I've tried to focus on that aspect of the question and to aid in answering it have researched a few online articles. Given the severity of the topic, I've also tried to only use articles from reputable(ish!) sources.

This is by no means a definitive answer and I do believe your question is so broad that it will be difficult to get anything like a single, definitive, objective answer. Additionally, there are so many resources available to answer the question, that it is hard to not automatically be drawn towards though which support your opinion (which is what happened to me in my answer below):

So first things first, what is a cult? From the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cult):

> A system of religious veneration and devotion directed towards a
>   particular figure or object.

An alternative, and more expansive, definiton is given by the [Cult Information Centre](http://www.cultinformation.org.uk/pdf/article_1.pdf):

> The Cult Information Centre (CIC) defines a cult as a group having all
>   of the following five characteristics:
>   1. It uses psychological coercion to recruit and indoctrinate potential members.
>   2. It forms an elitist totalitarian society.
>   3. Its founder leader is self-appointed, dogmatic, messianic, not accountable and has charisma.
>   4. It believes 'the end justifies the means' in order to solicit funds or recruit people.
>   5. Its wealth does not benefit its members or society.

In your example, that particular cult is focussed on devotion to Joe Carroll and your next obvious question was *why*?

[Feldman and Johnson](http://www.jaapl.org/content/23/2/239.full.pdf) [1995] describe some possible reasons:

> Members of cults are recruited and controlled by means of what
>   Hochman  describes as the concepts of "miracle,  mystery, and
>   authority." Miracle refers to  an ideology that ascribes special
>   powers  to the leaders and to the group's activities.  Mystery serves
>   to obscure the actual be-  liefs and goals of the group, such as 
>   power and control, and creates an atmos-  phere of awe. Authority
>   reflects the  claims on members' time, talents, lives,  and/or
>   property to meet the needs of the  group. Through these concepts the
>   cult  establishes dominance over individual  members.

This follows to a degree what [Abraham Maslow](http://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Maslow/motivation.htm) [1943] proposed in his now iconic "hierarchy of needs":

[image: Maslow]

He argued every person has fundamental needs (represented at the bottom of the pyramid) along with other needs such as the need for self actualisation. Maslow believed that the most basic level of needs had to be met before the person would strongly desire the higher needs.

In other words, using the diagram, he argued that people would fight for basic amenities like food, water and shelter, before longing for safety and security, before longing for love and companionship, before longing for the respect of others and a development of confidence, before longing for real personal enlightenment and development.

Using this structure along with the reasons provided by Feldman and Johnson, it's easy to see why people can be attracted to cults. People are given a false sense of safety, love and bbelonging. This false sense brings with it a fake sense of esteem. It then leads members to a form of self-actualisation, which can never succeed since they are trapped by the previous layers of the pyramid being created on false truths. Only when they break free of this can they truly develop.

In **The Following**, Joe Carroll met his followers in prison. He had years (nine I think) to slowly convert them to his way of thinking. They were all intrigued with him and he used this to corrupt them and offer them a sense of belonging that they felt they couldn't find anywhere else.

So I think this, coupled with the rest of the articles, provide some indication as to *why*
 people subscribed to his cult and ideas. However, one final question remains. Despite following him, why would people be moved to *kill* for him?

[Zimbardo](http://www.prisonexp.org/pdf/powerevil.pdf) presents this line of reasoning:

> Stanley Milgram (1974) developed an ingenious research procedure to
>   demonstrate the  extent to which situational forces could overwhelm
>   individual will to resist. He ‘shocked the  world’ with his unexpected
>   finding of extremely high rates of compliance to the demands of an 
>   authority figure to continue shocking an innocent victim to the
>   maximum possible level (also see  Blass, 2004). He found that about
>   67% of research participants “went all the way" up to the top  shock
>   level of 450 volts in shocking another person that were supposedly
>   helping. Milgram’s  study revealed that ordinary American citizens
>   could so easily be led to engage in “electrocuting  a nice stranger,”
>   as the Nazis had been led to murder Jews.

So I would argue this is why Joe Carroll's followers are able to go to such apparently astonishing lengths to follow his word. They trust him, he gives them a feeling of belonging and security and he rules them absolutely. This makes them believe they belong with him and as such lets him get away with poor treatment of them. After all, how could they turn away and reject him when, even when treating him badly, he still offers the best hope any of them could have (or so he's led them to believe). Given his power and dominance, they are willing to follow him blindly and have even become killers for him.

Hopefully these articles all provide some food for thought and give good answers to some of your questions. I will repeat though that this is by no means a definitive answer and someone with much more experience than me in the field of psychology would be the person to speak to!